# Is it possible to make JDBC connection with PDO?

Tags: java, php, jdbc, pdo, php-java-bridge

Is it possible to do something like

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

to

```
$pdo = new PDO("java:com/PakageName/jdbc/Driver");
```

by adding some .jar files in php project library?

I have made a simple PHP project and want to connect a database remotely which is providing JDBC driver.  Java program works fine but PDO will allow this ?

Answer (score 1):

**`JDBC`** is only for JAVA database connectivity. Here PHP can use **`ODBC`** Connection with **[PDO_ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php)**. ( Go through with the documentation )

**PDO_ODBC** is a driver that implements the PHP Data Objects (PDO) interface to enable access from PHP to databases through ODBC drivers.

Example:

```
<?php

  $dbh= new PDO('odbc:SOURCENAME', 'username', 'password');
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("$query");
  $stmt->execute();
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      print_r($row);
  }
  unset($dbh); unset($stmt);
?>
```

Useful link: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php

Comment: Thanks SHAZ for find time to answer. PHP-Java bridge will do the work like pass a query to java function and java function returns result or something like that.?