# Am I guaranteed to get consecutive ids with a single insert statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I insert 1000 rows with a single INSERT query. The query returns the id of the first inserted row. Is it save to assume that all other rows have the id `firstId + i` considering that there are possibly multiple of those insert queries running at the same time?

Comment: No is the simple answer

Answer (score 2):

Maybe. Usually yes, but there are a number of cases where this is not reliable.

The MySQL JDBC driver makes an assumption that a batch of generated auto-increment values are consecutive when you do a batch insert.

See the code in [java.com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.getGeneratedKeysInternal()](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/StatementImpl.java#L1429)

Simplifying the logic, the relevant bits are:

```
long beginAt = getLastInsertID();
for (int i = 0; i < numKeys; i++) {
    row[0] = StringUtils.getBytes(Long.toString(beginAt));
    beginAt += this.connection.getAutoIncrementIncrement();
}
```

So it starts at the id of the first inserted row, and it assumes subsequent generated id values are just the next `numKeys` values, incrementing by the `auto_increment_increment` config setting (which is 1 by default).

Can this go wrong? Yes, in a few cases. For example:

- If you do a multi-row `INSERT`, specifying a NULL for some rows and a real integer value for other rows in the same `INSERT` statement, the JDBC driver's assumption that all the values will be consecutive values after the value returned by `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is incorrect.
- If you do a multi-row `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or `REPLACE` where some rows exist and others don't, it will incorrectly report a set of consecutive generated keys.
- If you set `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2` (“interleaved” lock mode), then multi-row INSERT statements that run concurrently may not be consecutive. They will each generate id values whenever they can, and this will be unpredictably interleaved, like shuffling two halves of a deck of cards.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: I liked the simple answer

Comment: "Everything should be as simple as it can be, but not simpler."

Comment: If i use php (PDO) to connect to/insert into mysql, then as i understand PDO does not uses JDCB driver https://stackoverflow.com/a/34039878/2118559 Seems the answer does not apply to PDO... And seems in any case better not to rely that ids will correspond to the order of values in query.

Comment: @Andris, I mention JDBC in this answer just to demonstrate that an official MySQL Connector assumes id's generated in a multi-row INSERT are consecutive. We can take this as a sign that the makers of MySQL think it is reliable. The same behavior applies no matter what the client is, except in the cases I wrote about above.